# Android NDK debugging with ndk-gdb

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have installed the Android NDK via Android Studio (ndk version r13b). Building works fine and I am able to run my app on my device. However, whenever I try to run `ndk-gdb --verbose` to try and debug my app, I get a very vague error message:

```
ADB command used: '/home/nick/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s ZHR4H6EYFM59US55'
ADB version: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.36 Revision 0e9850346394-android
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nick/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/ndk-gdb.py", line 695, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/nick/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/ndk-gdb.py", line 598, in main
    args.props = device.get_props()
  File "/home/nick/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/python-packages/adb/device.py", line 495, in get_props
    raise RuntimeError('invalid getprop line: "{}"'.format(line))
RuntimeError: invalid getprop line: "[mtk.md1.starttime]: [1s Thu Dec 22 08:29:22 2016"
```

Unfortunately I have no idea what `invalid getprop line` means.

Answer (score 0):

So, there's actually a way to debug native code (even Native Activities) from Android Studio... so using ndk-gdk doesn't matter to me anymore